# Is there an R function to connect grouped data points created by a geom_() object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect the individual jittered data points that are created by geom_half_point(), and I tried to do this by adding geom_line() but this did not work. Does this mean that it is not possible to connect individual points based on a geom_() object like geom_half_point()?

See the figure here

[image: here]

And the minimal code I used to create this figure is:

```r
library(gghalves)

ggplot()+

  geom_half_violin(
    data = iris %>% filter(Species=="setosa"), 
    aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species), position = position_nudge(x = -.2, y = .2),side="l") +

  geom_half_boxplot(
    data = iris %>% filter(Species=="setosa"),
    aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species), position = position_nudge(x = -.15, y = .2), side = "r", center = TRUE, errorbar.draw = FALSE, width = .2) +

  geom_half_point(
    data = iris %>% filter(Species=="setosa"),
    aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species, color = Species), position = position_nudge(x = -.05, y = .2), side = "r", range_scale = .4) +

  geom_half_violin(
    data = iris %>% filter(Species=="versicolor"), 
    aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species), side="r") +

  geom_half_boxplot(
    data = iris %>% filter(Species=="versicolor"),
    aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species), position = position_nudge(x = -.2, y = .2), side = "r", center = TRUE, errorbar.draw = FALSE, width = .2) +

  geom_half_point(
    data = iris %>% filter(Species=="versicolor"), 
    aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species, color = Species), position = position_nudge(x = -.2, y = .2), side = "l", range_scale = .4) +

  scale_fill_manual(values = c("setosa" = "#cba1d2", "versicolor"="#7067CF","virginica"="#B7C0EE")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("setosa" = "#cba1d2", "versicolor"="#7067CF","virginica"="#B7C0EE")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Maybe give `ggalt::geom_encircle` a try, no idea if it will work with `geom_half_point` though. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalt/vignettes/ggalt_examples.html

Comment: I tried some out with ggalt functions, but I don't think that works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with discrete scales without artificially placing jitter values.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Species, x = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(position = "jitter") +
  geom_line()
```

This just plots a line through the grid line because the factor value is read as discrete values i.e. `1:3`

Below is an example of combining `geom_point` and `geom_line` as if it were on a discrete scale.

```
jitteramount <- runif(150,min=-.4,max=.4)
iris2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(lvl.val = as.numeric(Species),
         Species.val = lvl.val + jitteramount) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Species.val = scales::rescale(Species.val, to = c(min(lvl.val),min(lvl.val)+.3)))
ggplot(iris2, aes(x = Species.val, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  labs(x = "Species") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = levels(iris$Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_half_boxplot(side = "l", position= position_nudge(x=-.3)) +
  geom_half_violin(side = "l", position = position_nudge(x=-.5))
```

If you want the lines to connect vertically, you can arrange the points with `arrange` then use `geom_path`

```
ggplot(iris2 %>% group_by(Species) %>% arrange(Sepal.Length), aes(x = Species.val, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  labs(x = "Species") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = levels(iris$Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path() +
  geom_half_boxplot(side = "l", position= position_nudge(x=-.3)) +
  geom_half_violin(side = "l", position = position_nudge(x=-.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, not the best code, but will be optimized... thanks everyone
See the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W3kw.png)

```r
before = iris$Sepal.Length[1:50]
after = iris$Sepal.Length[51:100]
n <- length(before)
d <- data.frame(y = c(before, after), 
                x = rep(c(1,2), each=n),
                id = factor(rep(1:n,2)))

set.seed(321)    
d$xj <- jitter(d$x, amount=.09)
f1 <- ggplot(data=d, aes(y=y)) +
  #geom_boxplot(aes(x=x, group=x), width=0.2, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(x=xj), color = "gray47", size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x=xj, group=id), color = 'lightgray') +
  xlab("Condition") + ylab("Value") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2), labels=c("Before", "After"), limits=c(0, 3)) +
  theme_classic()+

  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "#cba1d2", "2"="#7067CF")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "#cba1d2", "2"="#7067CF")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(4, 8))

f2 <- f1 + 

  geom_half_boxplot(
    data = d %>% filter(x=="1"), 
    aes(x = x, y = y), position = position_nudge(x = -.25, y = .2), side = "r", center = TRUE, errorbar.draw = FALSE, width = .2, fill = '')

f3 <- f2 +  

  geom_half_boxplot(
        data = d %>% filter(x=="2"), 
  aes(x = x, y = y), position = position_nudge(x = .15, y = .2), side = "r", center = TRUE, errorbar.draw = FALSE, width = .2, fill = "")

f4 <- f3 +

    geom_half_violin(
    data = d %>% filter(x=="1"), 
    aes(x = x, y = y), position = position_nudge(x = -.3, y = .2), side = "l", fill = 'dodgerblue')

f5 <- f4 +

  geom_half_violin(
    data = d %>% filter(x=="2"),
    aes(x = x, y = y), position = position_nudge(x = .3, y = .2), side = "r", fill = "")
f5
```

Comment: this is a bit convoluted way of creating plots. It may be easier to plot simple facets. As for connecting dots with lines like this - a much clearer visualisation is to plot value y (after) against value x(before) on a simple scatter plot. This basically also removes the need for violin and box plot